# Re-arrange array on specific element

Tags: php, arrays

I need to change the order of array items to be as predefined order.

Original Array is

```
$order = array(3136,3121,3147,3125);

Array
(
    [3121] => Array
        (
            [0] => 311
            [1] => 311>
            [2] => First Level
        )

    [3125] => Array
        (
            [0] => 312
            [1] => 312>
            [2] => Ids
        )

    [3136] => Array
        (
            [0] => 313
            [1] => 313>
            [2] => Insurance
        )

    [3147] => Array
        (
            [0] => 314
            [1] => 314>
            [2] => Property
        )
)
```

Need to generate like below,

```
Array
(
    [3136] => Array
        (
            [0] => 313
            [1] => 313>
            [2] => Insurance
        )
    [3121] => Array
        (
            [0] => 311
            [1] => 311>
            [2] => First Level
        )
    [3147] => Array
        (
            [0] => 314
            [1] => 314>
            [2] => Property
        )
    [3125] => Array
        (
            [0] => 312
            [1] => 312>
            [2] => Ids
        )

)
```

Base will be the key of array element , after 3136 element 3121 will be pushed then 3147 and so on

Comment: What is the "algorithm" behind the "transformation" of the first array into the second one?

Comment: What's the logic behind the rearrangement?

Comment: any criteria for these changes ?

Comment: Your question is not clear...

Comment: Doesn't make any sense with provided information.

Comment: It is like a puzzle to solve: "guess what is the next number?"

Comment: Base will be the key of array element , after 3136 element 3121 will be pushed then 3147 and so on

Comment: You mean you have predefined order like: "I want the order of the new array to be = 3136,3121,3147"?

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess:

```
$order = array(3136,3121,3147);
$new_arr =array();
foreach ($order as $key){
    if ($old_array[$key])
        $new_arr[$key]=$old_array[$key];
}
```